# FB Canvas App not redirecting to Mobile Site URL using Canvas URL

Tags: facebook-canvas

I tried using the canvas url (https://apps.facebook.com/appnamespace) on mobile but getting a not found response from facebook. On desktop version functions as per normal.And this is happening on 2 of our new apps that are currently under test mode.

Comment: There is an open bug report open for this; the functionality is currently broken.

Answer (score 1):

Montaser Mossallem
I am using your method to create a redirect script in my FB canvas, but if I use smartphone to click this App, I will see the desktop-canvas screen and redirect to the mobile site soon. But I test your website  http://apps.facebook.com/funeral-buddy/ , It will directly redirect to mobile site without desktop-canvas screen.
Appreciate if you can tell me how to do it.  Many thanks

Bobby

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [Stack Overflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/about), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

Hi Could you see that on your mobile ? 
http://apps.facebook.com/funeral-buddy/ 
it works , the resolve you need to delete mobile site url from your facebook apps 
then put javascript code to handle it as a manually ,
check url if this url includes 'facebook' and check device if it mobile redirect them by this location.href

Comment: thanks so much removing the Mobile Site URL did the trick for our apps.

Comment: care to share the complete solution? which settings did you choose in Facebook App Settings and what is the redirect workflow?